ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/home/sbx_user1051/.config/w3access / vercel
am using w3up-client in a serverless function in node.js to upload some file to ipfs
the project works fine when run locally but throws this error ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/home/sbx_user1051/.config/w3access' after build and deploying on vercel.
i understand that ~/.config/w3acsess is directory for keys & delegation on linux but i can't figure out why it's showing up here as i'm on windows
here's the code ..
async function uploadFileToIPFS(postData) {
try {
const { StoreMemory } = await import(
"@web3-storage/w3up-client/stores/memory"
);

    const { create } = await import("@web3-storage/w3up-client"); // Use dynamic import()
    const store = new StoreMemory();
    
    // Create a client instance
    const client = await create(store);
    
    
    
    // 4. Provision the space with your account
    await client.setCurrentSpace(
      "did:key:z6MkhbGhvyJPTMPZGopGDknW3ij1WQ5yJmfDKS4G1K5gPtkn"
    );
    
    // Convert JSON object to a Blob
    const jsonBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(postData)], {
      type: "application/json",
    });
    
    const fileCid = await client.uploadFile(jsonBlob);
    
    console.log(`File uploaded successfully! CID: ${fileCid}`);

